# Problem running apt

Tags: apt, grub2, package-management, kernel, dpkg

When I try to do any updates or do an autoremove on Ubuntu MATE 20.04, I get the following:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_    55nzf7'.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.4.0-96-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-5.4.0-96-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.4.0-96-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
ZSys is adding automatic system snapshot to GRUB menu
ERROR "update-grub" returned an error: exit status 1 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: please can you add `dpkg -l| egrep -v '^ii|rc'` to your question. dpkg: too many errors  maybe other packages are also involved And `dkms status` also please. If system says command not found forget about dkms.

Comment: I found a nice answer possibly related to the problem here: [Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Failed to Install linux-image-5.4.0-89-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1371963/ubuntu-20-04-lts-failed-to-install-linux-image-5-4-0-89-generic)

Comment: Please [edit] to add the output of `sudo apt -f install` and `sudo update-grub`. Also, add the output of `cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-5.4.0-96-generic.postrm`.