# Cannot use dpkg or update anything due to kernel

Tags: boot, kernel, updates, dpkg, filesystem

since today I have noticed that I cannot install gparted or even check for updates because of unknown error. All I understand is that kernel does not allow to be removed and stops any process that I try to run in the terminal. I have tried force remove.
I would also like to mention that my OS does not see grub?

This is the output.

Can someone please explain to me what is happening and how do I fix this issue?

```
Setting up grub-pc (2.06-2ubuntu12.1) ...

/var/lib/dpkg/info/grub-pc.config: 12: /etc/default/grub: Usage:: not found
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 installed grub-pc package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Setting up linux-image-5.19.0-26-generic (5.19.0-26.27) ...
Setting up linux-image-5.15.0-56-generic (5.15.0-56.62) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-efi-amd64-signed:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64 | grub-pc; however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64 is not installed.
  Package grub-pc is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.19.0-26-generic (5.19.0-26.27) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.19.0-26-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dracut:
dracut: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-26-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 12: /etc/default/grub: Usage:: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.19.0-26-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.19.0-26-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.15.0-56-generic (5.15.0-56.62) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.15.0-56-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dracut:
dracut: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-56-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 12: /etc/default/grub: Usage:: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.15.0-56-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.15.0-56-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1

**Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
 linux-image-5.19.0-26-generic
 linux-image-5.15.0-56-generic
```

This is what I cannot understand at all

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu, and how did you install kernel `5.19.0-26-generic`? Please include in your question.

Comment: I had similar problem and this answer was helpful: https://askubuntu.com/a/1372049/238032