# apt upgrade error: cannot remove '/lib/modules/5.15.0-71-generic/kernel/drivers/rtc/rtc-ds1511.ko': Input/output error

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

Trying to run `sudo apt upgrade` on Ubuntu server 22.04.1 LTS and get the following error (copying the whole output)

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libflashrom1 libftdi1-2 libllvm13
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-71-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-5.15.0-73 linux-headers-5.15.0-73-generic linux-image-5.15.0-73-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-73-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-73-generic python3-magic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  alsa-ucm-conf apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils apparmor apport apt apt-utils base-files bind9-dnsutils bind9-host bind9-libs binutils
  binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu ca-certificates cpp-11 cryptsetup cryptsetup-bin cryptsetup-initramfs distro-info-data dmidecode dpkg
  firmware-sof-signed fwupd fwupd-signed g++-11 gcc-11 gcc-11-base grub-common grub-efi-amd64 grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed grub2-common
  gzip initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin initramfs-tools-core intel-media-va-driver iptables isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common kbd libapparmor1
  libapt-pkg6.0 libasan6 libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libbinutils libcryptsetup12 libctf-nobfd0 libctf0 libcups2
  libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-common libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 libfwupd2 libfwupdplugin5 libgcc-11-dev libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-data libgssapi-krb5-2 libip4tc2 libip6tc2 libk5crypto3 libkrb5-3
  libkrb5support0 libldap-2.5-0 libldap-common libllvm15 libmbim-glib4 libmbim-proxy libmm-glib0 libncurses6 libncursesw6 libnetplan0 libnftables1
  libnss-systemd libpam-systemd libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpulse0 libpython3-stdlib libqmi-glib5 libqmi-proxy libsasl2-2
  libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules-db libssl3 libstdc++-11-dev libsystemd0 libtinfo6 libtsan0 libudev1 libxtables12 linux-firmware linux-generic
  linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic linux-libc-dev mdadm mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers modemmanager mokutil
  motd-news-config ncurses-base ncurses-bin ncurses-term netplan.io nftables open-vm-tools openssh-client openssh-server openssh-sftp-server openssl
  python-apt-common python3 python3-apport python3-apt python3-distupgrade python3-distutils python3-gdbm python3-lib2to3 python3-minimal
  python3-problem-report python3-software-properties python3-tz python3-update-manager shim-signed snapd software-properties-common sosreport systemd
  systemd-sysv systemd-timesyncd tcpdump thermald tzdata ubuntu-advantage-tools ubuntu-release-upgrader-core udev update-manager-core
  update-notifier-common
155 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
32 standard security updates
Need to get 0 B/525 MB of archives.
After this operation, 254 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 149403 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-71-generic (5.15.0-71.78) ...
dpkg: error processing package linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-71-generic (--remove):
 cannot remove '/lib/modules/5.15.0-71-generic/kernel/drivers/rtc/rtc-ds1511.ko': Input/output error
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-71-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: see this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1372049/1698042

Comment: Boot up a live session and make a filesystem check. Good idea would also be to check healthy of hard-drive with smartmontools.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that the hard drive had some health issues.